# Why can't I place an array of objects in of in the resources of my root control?

Tags: wpf, arrays, xaml, instantiation

Suppose I have a normal Xaml file with two extra xmlns, one to a "Person" Class with two CLR properties "Name" and "Age", and one to a String object:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPractice.ListBinding"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPractice"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"        
    Title="ListBinding" Height="200" Width="600">
```

I can place an array of strings in the Resources collection of my root window element:

```
    <Window.Resources>  
        <x:Array x:Key="ThisWorks" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">  
            <sys:String>John</sys:String>  
            <sys:String>Andy</sys:String>  
        </x:Array>  
    </Window.Resources>
```

I can also instantiate an object in the resources of the root control:

```
    <Window.Resources>  
        <local:Person x:Key="ThisAlsoWorks" Name="Michael" Age="40"/>  
    </Window.Resources>
```

But VS won't let me build if I instantiate an array of ojects in the resources of the root control:

```
    <Window.Resources>  
        <x:Array x:Key="ThisWontBuild" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">  
            <local:Person Name="Michael" Age="40"/>  
            <local:Person Name="Jim" Age="30"/>   
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Howwver VS will build if I instantiate the array of ojects in the resources of a child control such as a grid:

```
    <Grid.Resources>  
        <x:Array x:Key="ThisWillBuild" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">  
            <local:Person Name="Michael" Age="40"/>  
            <local:Person Name="Jim" Age="30"/>   
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: The class can't initialize:  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you were lacking the respective `xmlns` on the root element?

I cannot think of any other reason why it would not work and i can tell you that it is certainly possible as i do that quite frequently.

Comment: I don't change anything to the Xaml file, just the location of the Array, and it works if I put the array in the grid but not the root element. How bizarre!

Comment: There has to be *some* difference between the two elements, i for one never had such problems.

Comment: H.B. was right; it was a problem with my code. I had another Resource in the ResourceCollection of the root window element that was interfearing with the code:

    <Window.Resources>  
        <local:AnotherList x:Key="myOtherList"/>  
    </Window.Resources>

If I remove this Resource than I can instantiate an array of Person objects in the root window resource colection.

Answer (score 0):

use sys instead of x as xmlns of Array.hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As I said the problem was with my code but the answer is even more bizarre than I thought. I had an another class in my code-behind whose only property returns a List:

```
public class CreateList
{
    public CreateList()
    {
        _createdList.Add("carrot");
        _createdList.Add("fox");
        _createdList.Add("explorer");
    }

    List<string> _createdList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> CreatedList
    {
        get { return _createdList; }
    }
}
```

If I have a resource pointing to an array as well as a resource pointing to the CreateList class in the root window element (in that order), VS builds without any problem. So using the window root element header I described in the question this works:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="Office" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <local:Person Name="Michael" Age="40"/>
        <local:Person Name="Jim" Age="30"/>
        <local:Person Name="Dwight" Age="30"/>
    </x:Array>
    <local:CreateList x:Key="myCreateList"/>       
</Window.Resources>
```

However if I put the resource pointing to CreateList first, VS doesn't build!!!

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CreateList x:Key="myCreateList"/>
    <x:Array x:Key="Office" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <local:Person Name="Michael" Age="40"/>
        <local:Person Name="Jim" Age="30"/>
        <local:Person Name="Dwight" Age="30"/>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
```

The same problem occurs if I have an array of strings, but not if I use a single string or Person object. Weird huh? So I have answered my original question, but now I have a new question! Typical.

Comment: And that seems to be a known [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535422/wpf-static-list-causes-compile-error) with low prio to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have a similar problem.  If the x:Array was declared as a Resource on my UserControl, I got the compiler error.  I found I was able to move the declaration of the x:Array onto a DockPanel within the UserControl, and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Person class.

```
namespace WpfPractice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Reference
[C# wpf Can't create an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602001/c-sharp-wpf-cant-create-an-array-of-objects/32602174)